# Access to ITableFields interface from an ITable or IObjectClass interface

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, file-geodatabase

I am working in a File Geo Database and need to set certain columns to be readonly from an ArcMap user perspective only.  I am aware of the `IFieldEdit.Editable` property, however that locks it down from me being able to edit the columns programmatically as well.

On the feature layer level this is easily done by casting the `IFeatureLayer` interface to `ITableFields` and accessing the `IFieldInfo3` interface for that specific field as such:

```
public static bool isFieldReadOnly(IFeatureLayer featureLayer, string fieldName)
{
        ITableFields tableFields = (ITableFields)featureLayer;
        IFieldInfo3 fieldInfo = (IFieldInfo3)tableFields.get_FieldInfo(tableFields.FindField(fieldName));
        return fieldInfo.Readonly;
}
```

However, how can this be done on an ITable or IObjectClass interface?

I have an `ITable` created in the same workspace using `IFeatureWorkspace.CreateTable(...)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success!

For tables other than the FeatureLayer, you have to do the following:

1. Create a StandaloneTableClass, set the Table property, you may now access and setup any properties you like from the IFieldInfo interface.
2. After that you have to add the StandaloneTable to the map by casting IMap to IStandaloneTableCollection.

> ITable = ...// Create your table here
>
> IMap map = ...// Reference to IMap here
>
> IStandaloneTable stdTable = new StandaloneTableClass();
>
> stdTable.Table = table;
>
> ITableFields tableFields = (ITableFields)stdTable;
>
> IFieldInfo3 fieldInfo = (IFieldInfo3)tableFields.get_FieldInfo(tableFields.FindField(fieldName));
>
> fieldInfo.Readonly = readOnly;
>
> // Add your featureLayers to the map
>
> IStandaloneTableCollection coll = (IStandaloneTableCollection)map;
>
> coll.AddStandaloneTable(stdTable);

Answer (score 0):

The description of [IFieldInfo3.Readonly Property](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Readonly_Property/00250000035w000000/) says,

> Setting the value to true will make the field read only in clients
>   such as the ArcMap editor attribute window. This property only applies
>   to clients that choose to implement it.

So I think you can only restrict the user only after the feature class is added to map as a layer.

Comment: In my case I am adding the IFeatureLayer to the map *after* setting the IFieldInfo3.Readonly property to true and it works just fine.  The question is how to access this ability on a relationship table.